# Remove salt and pepper noise in frequency domain using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

How can I remove impulse noise (especially salt and pepper noise) in frequency domain instead of spatial domain using Matlab ?

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do that ? What's wrong with just using e.g. a median filter ?

Comment: Is your transformed signal influenced by (salt and pepper) noise? Or do you transform a noisy signal into the frequency domain?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger I transform a noisy signal into the frequency domain